# how tho change number of posts in loop from specific categories

Tags: categories, loop, query

I am trying to get my home loop query filled like this:

1. From all posts within all categories: show (just) 1 (most recent) post.
2. From some specific categories: show 3 (most recent) posts (max).
3. Sort on publish date.

website: [www.baiweb.nl](http://www.baiweb.nl)

The combination of 1,3 and 2,3 is pretty standard, but I can't figure out how to script the two combined.

Appreciate getting some help!

Answer (score 0):

I found this item, that might be a good start; but the difference is that we need not to specify each specific category, the basic must be, one itme of all recent posts.
[how tho change number of posts in loop from specific categories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378236/how-tho-change-number-of-posts-in-loop-from-specific-categories)